# Removing background "grid" in photosop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I am completely new to photoshop, so apologies for the simple question. I need to remove the background grid from this image, as shown below:

[image]
I would like the circular portion to take up the entirety of the image. How can I do this?

Comment: Top menu: `Image > Trim`.

Comment: Aha! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to remove the background grid is to apply a solid colour layer (you can choose whatever colour you like).

[image]

If your goal is to save the file only with a the circle though you'll have to keep the grid (in order to have a transparent background) and save the file in png

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me.